# Phoenix - (ErlangError) erlang error: :"module could not be loaded"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a simple Phoenix Channel to handle websockets for messages. I tried adding insertion of a model into the database and am getting this error when I pass these message params in.

```
def handle_in("new:msg", msg, socket) do
  message_params = %{"body" => msg["body"]}
  changeset = Message.changeset(%Message{}, message_params)

  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, room} ->
      broadcast! socket, "new:msg", %{user: msg["user"], body: msg["body"]}
      {:reply, {:ok, %{msg: msg["body"]}}, assign(socket, :user, msg["user"])}
    {:error, changeset} ->
  end
end
```

Here's the error. Any ideas on what this could be are more than welcome.

```
Repo.insert(%Ecto.Changeset{action: nil, changes: %{body: "feaflje"}, constraints: [], errors: [], filters: %{}, model: %PulseApi.Message{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built>, body: nil, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, room: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :room is not loaded>, room_id: nil, updated_at: nil}, optional: [], opts: [], params: %{"body" => "feaflje"}, repo: nil, required: [:body], types: %{body: :string, id: :id, inserted_at: Ecto.DateTime, room_id: :id, updated_at: Ecto.DateTime}, valid?: true, validations: []})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the name of the project to correctly namespace Repo to get this to work.

Repo had to be ProjectName.Repo

```
case PulseApi.Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, room} ->
    broadcast! socket, "new:msg", %{user: msg["user"], body: msg["body"]}
    {:reply, {:ok, %{msg: msg["body"]}}, assign(socket, :user, msg["user"])}
  {:error, changeset} ->
end
```